# How can I create multiple rows of dots that are closely set together?

Tags: html, css

I am interested in creating a series of dots that are very close together, like how they have it on the Bloomberg website: http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/commodities

How can I create this? I especially don't know how to create the close compact lines in between the rows.

```
.underlined {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Got the pattern,  review my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect element

#### SNIPPET

```css
.dots {
line-height:17px;
  }
.dots:before{
 background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAFUlEQVQIW2P83Sf3n7XoESMjAxQAADjFBAPqoJzEAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
    text-indent: -119988px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    content: "pattern dots";
    height: 1.25rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Comment: what is the background image of?

Comment: A gif of one little orange dot at 2x2px if I recall correctly. It's then repeated horizontally and vertically within the parameters of the div's dimensions. It takes one less http request fortunately.

Answer (score 1):

the solution can be found in this link

https://codepen.io/aleprieto/pen/nAmIy

```
<div class="dotted">Dotted</div>
<style>
  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
  div {
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 21px 'Oswald',sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff, 2px 2px 0 #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .dotted {
    padding: 2.25em 1.6875em;
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
    background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
    -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px;
    -moz-background-size: 3px 3px;
    background-size: 3px 3px;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Actual solution is @zer00ne's answer